# Overcoming java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException

Tags: java

I am currently trying to complete a project to determine the rate of investment and such for a 5 year term with a 2.5 rate of interest starting at 1000. i keep getting tripped up on line 22 with a java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: null.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class midtermpracticeb
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        double investment;
        double rateOfReturn;
        int term;

        System.out.print ("What is the value of the initial investment? ");
        investment = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print ("What is the Rate of Return? ");
        rateOfReturn = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print ("What is the term of the investment? ");
        term = in.nextInt();

        System.out.printf ("%6s %6s %6s\n", "Year", "Interest", "Balance");
        System.out.printf ("%6s %6s %6s\n", "=====", "=========", "=========");
        for (term = 0; term < 5; term++)
        {
            System.out.printf ("%6s %6.2f\n",term);
            System.out.printf ("%6s %6.2f\n", rateOfReturn);
            double interest = investment * rateOfReturn;
            System.out.printf ("6s %6.2f\n", interest);
            double x = Math.round (investment * 100.0)/100.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your number of parameters doesn't match your number of format specifiers.Sorry, but this isn't a Java problem but a basic math problem. e.g, `System.out.printf ("%6s %6.2f\n",term);` two specifiers, but one variable, just doesn't add up. Again, this is just common sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("%6s %6.2f\n", term);
```

The format string has two parameters `%6s` and `%6.2f`, so you need to give it two arguments. But you've only given one (`term`).